# apple customerreviews with rss2email (list of countries or app stores)

Tags: rss, app-store-connect

In iTunesConnect you can open rss feeds for the customer reviews of your app:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=123/sortBy=mostRecent/xml
https://itunes.apple.com/de/rss/customerreviews/id=123/sortBy=mostRecent/xml
```

The top level folder (us/de/..) of the URL changes for each country, the parameter id is the store id of the app. (here 123)

With rss2email you can check the feeds and send an email when somebody posts a review. So far, so good.

My problem is, that in iTunesConnect there are only six countries in the dropdown, where somebody has actually posted a review. But I cannot find out, what other country codes (us/de/..) there are, so I will miss reviews from other countries.

I have tried parsing possible codes from this page and got 73 two character codes:

```
http://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/
```

But this has resulted in most reviews triggering up to five emails and I don't see, which country codes have caused them or if there might be stores with codes longer than two characters.

Does anyone maybe know, how/where to get a list of all valid countries/appstores without those causing duplicates?

edit: i could not add tags for "rss2email" and "customerreviews" ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the country list of the Country dropdown input list of the following url:

http://itunes.apple.com/rss/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you got the question resolved by now but in following link you can check appstore country codes: [AppStore Territories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/C_AppStoreTerritories/AppStoreTerritories.html)

Comment: Okay, looks more offical, but it contains the same data RSC has posted, so will leave his answer as correct because he was faster. :) Thanks!

Comment: The working link now is [App Store countries and regions](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev997f9cf7c)

Answer (score 0):

[https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=[app-id]&country=[country-code]](https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=%5Bapp-id%5D&country=%5Bcountry-code%5D)

**Example URL**: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=297606951&country=us

**Example Response**:

```json
{
  "resultCount": 1,
  "results": [{
    "supportedDevices": ["iPhone5s-iPhone5s", "iPadAir-iPadAir", "iPadAirCellular-iPadAirCellular", "iPadMiniRetina-iPadMiniRetina", "iPadMiniRetinaCellular-iPadMiniRetinaCellular", "iPhone6-iPhone6", "iPhone6Plus-iPhone6Plus", "iPadAir2-iPadAir2", "iPadAir2Cellular-iPadAir2Cellular", "iPadMini3-iPadMini3", "iPadMini3Cellular-iPadMini3Cellular", "iPodTouchSixthGen-iPodTouchSixthGen", "iPhone6s-iPhone6s", "iPhone6sPlus-iPhone6sPlus", "iPadMini4-iPadMini4", "iPadMini4Cellular-iPadMini4Cellular", "iPadPro-iPadPro", "iPadProCellular-iPadProCellular", "iPadPro97-iPadPro97", "iPadPro97Cellular-iPadPro97Cellular", "iPhoneSE-iPhoneSE", "iPhone7-iPhone7", "iPhone7Plus-iPhone7Plus", "iPad611-iPad611", "iPad612-iPad612", "iPad71-iPad71", "iPad72-iPad72", "iPad73-iPad73", "iPad74-iPad74", "iPhone8-iPhone8", "iPhone8Plus-iPhone8Plus", "iPhoneX-iPhoneX", "iPad75-iPad75", "iPad76-iPad76", "iPhoneXS-iPhoneXS", "iPhoneXSMax-iPhoneXSMax", "iPhoneXR-iPhoneXR", "iPad812-iPad812", "iPad834-iPad834", "iPad856-iPad856", "iPad878-iPad878", "iPadMini5-iPadMini5", "iPadMini5Cellular-iPadMini5Cellular", "iPadAir3-iPadAir3", "iPadAir3Cellular-iPadAir3Cellular", "iPodTouchSeventhGen-iPodTouchSeventhGen", "iPhone11-iPhone11", "iPhone11Pro-iPhone11Pro", "iPadSeventhGen-iPadSeventhGen", "iPadSeventhGenCellular-iPadSeventhGenCellular", "iPhone11ProMax-iPhone11ProMax", "iPhoneSESecondGen-iPhoneSESecondGen", "iPadProSecondGen-iPadProSecondGen", "iPadProSecondGenCellular-iPadProSecondGenCellular", "iPadProFourthGen-iPadProFourthGen", "iPadProFourthGenCellular-iPadProFourthGenCellular", "iPhone12Mini-iPhone12Mini", "iPhone12-iPhone12", "iPhone12Pro-iPhone12Pro", "iPhone12ProMax-iPhone12ProMax", "iPadAir4-iPadAir4", "iPadAir4Cellular-iPadAir4Cellular", "iPadEighthGen-iPadEighthGen", "iPadEighthGenCellular-iPadEighthGenCellular", "iPadProThirdGen-iPadProThirdGen", "iPadProThirdGenCellular-iPadProThirdGenCellular", "iPadProFifthGen-iPadProFifthGen", "iPadProFifthGenCellular-iPadProFifthGenCellular", "iPhone13Pro-iPhone13Pro", "iPhone13ProMax-iPhone13ProMax", "iPhone13Mini-iPhone13Mini", "iPhone13-iPhone13", "iPadMiniSixthGen-iPadMiniSixthGen", "iPadMiniSixthGenCellular-iPadMiniSixthGenCellular", "iPadNinthGen-iPadNinthGen", "iPadNinthGenCellular-iPadNinthGenCellular", "iPhoneSEThirdGen-iPhoneSEThirdGen", "iPadAirFifthGen-iPadAirFifthGen", "iPadAirFifthGenCellular-iPadAirFifthGenCellular"],
    "features": ["iosUniversal"],
    "advisories": [],
    "isGameCenterEnabled": false,
    "screenshotUrls": [
      "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/PurpleSource115/v4/f6/33/7b/f6337b0c-2671-e2b4-002f-0a36fab77e71/17eaa185-7352-4096-b55c-0bae474b4199_Apple_5.5_1242x2208_IntroScreen.png/392x696bb.png",
      "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple125/v4/ce/2f/11/ce2f115f-e0df-cf9d-4c72-d0cc4f7091e8/2150888f-4c22-4325-99a9-5d482b1655f9_1242x2208_Screen1.png/392x696bb.png",
      "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple115/v4/18/d9/8c/18d98c8b-ac4f-ee10-d6f5-78b83231b361/dc6e2c88-148f-4e8c-bb8b-52a28e6f0964_1242x2208_Screen2.png/392x696bb.png",
      "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple125/v4/24/47/4a/24474a84-9822-7713-7756-6ac963cf89bb/098cc97c-bf76-4aca-b1c3-36c7e4219a74_1242x2208_Screen3.png/392x696bb.png",
      "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple115/v4/8b/d4/31/8bd43171-4bae-a895-6bba-1a4dd6c019b3/58ae38d7-8318-4e21-a418-2a8de41525f9_1242x2208_Screen4.png/392x696bb.png",
      "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple115/v4/94/cf/b6/94cfb621-7843-b73e-8d94-1116bd088796/21c4c003-5d3e-4793-8b58-11b24e5be2af_1242x2208_Screen5.png/392x696bb.png",
      "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple115/v4/b7/ff/32/b7ff32fc-40f7-8fbc-c47f-e6199fdd46cc/0d923ffa-5cf0-4fcc-990c-be0252f7e6e5_1242x2208_Screen6.png/392x696bb.png"
    ],
    "ipadScreenshotUrls": ["https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple125/v4/b0/da/7a/b0da7a66-25ab-0fc0-704f-b5dc60530566/pr_source.png/576x768bb.png", "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple115/v4/c9/19/ef/c919ef13-664e-0d0f-01fc-0d456b56c2c8/pr_source.png/576x768bb.png", "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple115/v4/28/9e/4a/289e4a6c-6428-53fd-fde1-0efa40e64a78/pr_source.png/576x768bb.png", "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple115/v4/be/1c/67/be1c678b-4f3f-33c3-fbaa-8e8be720911b/pr_source.png/576x768bb.png", "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple125/v4/e1/94/bf/e194bf78-08ea-e419-7bf8-dbb476dbed58/pr_source.png/576x768bb.png", "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple125/v4/92/95/84/929584ee-7825-9d7b-1a65-22a08a337203/pr_source.png/576x768bb.png", "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple115/v4/d8/88/eb/d888eb7d-0203-07e9-0cb7-2bd86e8202c5/pr_source.png/576x768bb.png", "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple125/v4/ed/99/82/ed9982f2-9f91-70f8-7cff-db3be3e24221/pr_source.png/576x768bb.png"],
    "appletvScreenshotUrls": [],
    "artworkUrl60": "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple112/v4/27/fb/42/27fb42b0-925f-1a86-abe8-4722e884d8bd/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-6-0-0-85-220-0.png/60x60bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl512": "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple112/v4/27/fb/42/27fb42b0-925f-1a86-abe8-4722e884d8bd/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-6-0-0-85-220-0.png/512x512bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl100": "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple112/v4/27/fb/42/27fb42b0-925f-1a86-abe8-4722e884d8bd/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-6-0-0-85-220-0.png/100x100bb.jpg",
    "artistViewUrl": "https://apps.apple.com/us/developer/amzn-mobile-llc/id297606954?uo=4",
    "kind": "software",
    "releaseNotes": "Our new design provides easier access to the features you use most while on the go. This includes the homepage, account and order information, your cart and the ability to browse and discover Amazon departments, products, programs, and features.",
    "bundleId": "com.amazon.Amazon",
    "primaryGenreName": "Shopping",
    "primaryGenreId": 6024,
    "sellerName": "AMZN Mobile LLC",
    "genreIds": ["6024", "6012"],
    "isVppDeviceBasedLicensingEnabled": true,
    "currentVersionReleaseDate": "2022-08-22T18:53:31Z",
    "currency": "USD",
    "trackCensoredName": "Amazon Shopping",
    "languageCodesISO2A": ["AR", "EN", "FR", "DE", "IT", "JA", "PT", "ZH", "ES"],
    "fileSizeBytes": "163086336",
    "sellerUrl": "https://www.amazon.com/",
    "formattedPrice": "Free",
    "contentAdvisoryRating": "4+",
    "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion": 4.852289999999999992041921359486877918243408203125,
    "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion": 7564184,
    "averageUserRating": 4.852289999999999992041921359486877918243408203125,
    "trackViewUrl": "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amazon-shopping/id297606951?uo=4",
    "trackContentRating": "4+",
    "minimumOsVersion": "13.0",
    "version": "19.16.0",
    "wrapperType": "software",
    "releaseDate": "2008-12-03T08:00:00Z",
    "trackId": 297606951,
    "trackName": "Amazon Shopping",
    "artistId": 297606954,
    "artistName": "AMZN Mobile LLC",
    "genres": ["Shopping", "Lifestyle"],
    "price": 0.00,
    "description": "Amazon Shopping offers app-only benefits to help make shopping on Amazon faster and easier. Browse, view product details, read reviews, and purchase millions of products. Amazon delivers to 100+ countries in as quickly as 3-5 days. Whether you’re buying gifts, reading reviews, tracking orders, scanning products, or just shopping, the Amazon Shopping app offers more benefits than shopping on Amazon via your desktop.   \n\nNever miss a delivery\nGet real-time tracking and delivery notifications so you know where your package is and when it arrives. \n\nKnow exactly what you’re purchasing\nFull 360° product view lets you see items from every angle. “View in you room” makes sure it fits by using your phone’s camera and VR so you can see it in your space. \n\nWe’ll notify you when items go on sale\nJust tap the heart icon to save items to Your Lists and we’ll alert you of price drops so you don’t miss a deal. \n\nNever forget your password\nSave time by staying securely signed in. If you prefer to sign out, use facial or fingerprint identification to sign back in. \n\nConnect with us when it works best for you\nLive chat support is open 24 hours, 7 days a week. Once you’ve started a chat, it stays that way for 24 hours so you don’t have to start your support session from the beginning. \n\nWe’ll find that item for you\nNot sure of an item’s brand or where to but it? Just tap the scan icon in the search bar, take a picture of the item or its barcode, and we’ll find it for you. \n\nIn order to provide a rich experience and enable features such as voice shopping, notifications, visual search, customer reviews, and authentication this app may request permission to access contacts, camera, microphone, notification, touch id, photos and Bluetooth.\n\nAmazon Shopping is available in English, Spanish, German, and Simplified Chinese. In addition to International Shopping, you can change your settings in this single app to shop Amazon.ca, Amazon.co.uk, Amazon.de, Amazon.fr, Amazon.com, Amazon.it, Amazon.es, Amazon.cn, Amazon.co.jp or Amazon.in.\n\nFor customers located within the European Union, United Kingdom or Brazil: By using this app, you agree to Amazon’s Conditions of Use applicable for your country. Please also see the applicable Privacy Notice, Cookies Notice and Interest-Based Ads Notice for your country. Links to these terms and notices can be found in the footer of your local Amazon homepage.\n\nFor all other customers: By using this app, you agree to the applicable Amazon Conditions of Use (e.g. www.amazon.com/conditionsofuse) and Privacy Notice (e.g. www.amazon.com/privacy) for your country. Links to these terms and notices can be found in the footer of your local Amazon homepage.\n\nIf your device supports TrueDepth technology, the app will use your device camera to detect your facial movements only while using certain features such as virtually try-on products like sunglasses. All information processed using this technology remains on your device and is not otherwise stored, processed or shared by Amazon.",
    "userRatingCount": 7564184
  }]
}
```